# (In Python) What's the difference between list(string).reverse() and list(string)[::-1]?

Tags: python, list, iterable

I can execute both expressions in Python shell without error:

> string = 'this is a string'
>   list(string)[::-1]
>
> (output) ['g', 'n', 'i', 'r', 't', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 's', 'i', ' ', 's', 'i', 'h', 't']
>
> list(string).reverse()

I can do:

> string = ''.join(list(string)[::-1])

which effectively reverse the string in place. However when I do:

> string = ''.join(list(string).reverse()

I got an error:

> TypeError: can only join an iterable

So list(string).reverse() does not return an iterable but list(string)[::-1] does. Can someone help me understand the underlying differences?

Comment: It's worth noting that strings are sliceable directly, you don't need to create a list first and `join` the letters back together. Just use `string[::-1]`.

Answer (score 7):

`list(string).reverse()` modifies the list in place and returns `None`

So you are are doing:

```
"".join(None)
```

Hence the error.

Answer (score 4):

`list.reverse()` mutates the list it is called from so the list is altered after the call, while `sequence[::-1]` creates a new list and returns it, so the original list is unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

`list.reverse` is returning `None` so you don't need to assign it back, but, `seq[::-1]` needs to be assigned back, Example:

```
l=[1,2,3]
print(l.reverse())
print(l)
```

Output:

```
None
[3,2,1]
```

Example 2:

```
l=['a','b','c']
print(l[::-1])
print(l)
```

Output:

```
['c','b','a']
['a','b','c']
```

Example 2 needs to be assigned back